# Mysql 8.0_ Create new db_ "Schema directory already exists"

Tags: mysql, database, windows

Im trying this in Mysql 8.0:
"  CREATE SCHEMA `test`;  "
but an error appears:
"Error Code: 3678. Schema directory '.\test' already exists. This must be resolved manually (e.g. by moving the schema directory to another location)."   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Wac.png)
Where can I find that directory to eliminate it? OS: Windows.

windows 10 home (Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18362.418]).

I installed in program files(

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0)

<DIR> bin 14/10/2019 13:26 
<DIR> docs 14/10/2019 13:26 
<DIR> etc 14/10/2019 13:26 
<DIR> include 14/10/2019 13:26 
<DIR> lib 25/06/2019 12:23 336,955 
LICENSE 25/06/2019 12:23 101,805 
LICENSE.router 25/06/2019 12:23 687 
README 25/06/2019 12:23 700 
README.router 14/10/2019 13:26 
<DIR> share
```

Comment: Try to run `select @@datadir`.

Comment: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Data\\'
I go there but "Data" doesnt exists. Im showing all folders (hidden too) but nothing.

Comment: Specify Windows version, it may help people help you.

Comment: Where did you install MySQL

Comment: windows 10 home (Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18362.418]) .I installed in program files(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0). I only have these folders and archives : bin, docs, etc, includ, lib, LICENSE, LICENSE.router, README, README.router, share

Comment: And what was the result of running `select @@datadir`

Comment: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Data\\'

Comment: Very odd. Did the install give you any errors?

Comment: No, Everything is ok but i dont have access to that folder

Comment: I would suggest Uninstalling and then reboot and Install MySQL again being very aware of everything you are asked to do

Answer (score 2):

In the directories where the database is stored there is a "test" folder.

**You must rename or delete the "test" folder** in order to create a new database or a new schema called "test" because doing so generates a folder with that name, but since a folder with that name already exists, the error it gives you occurs.

Answer (score 2):

For the people who are working with WAMP and having the same issue

You can find the folder in "C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql\data" and simply delete the relevant folder you get the error on.
(Try renaming it if you don't want to delete the folder)

Answer (score 0):

all databases which you created were stored in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server **\Data". find the folder/db you wanna move/remove and delete it. This worked for me. :)