# Docker MYSQL initialize with default data

Tags: mysql, docker

When I run docker, it tries to delete the database if It exists else creates one.

I face the below error of "./SomeDB already exists . This must be resolved manually problem". this happens if Line 1 and 2 are available.

If I delete them and use line 3 it works fine. I also manually delete the data directory , docker fresh start but still get the same error.

```
Line 1: drop database IF EXISTS SomeDB;
Line 2: create database SomeDB;
Line 3: use SomeDB;
```

```
mysql   | 2023-11-06 06:31:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a.sql
mysql   | ERROR 3678 (HY000) at line 2: Schema directory './SomeDB' already exists. This must be resolved manually (e.g. by moving the schema directory to another location).
```

Docker compose has following configuration for volumes

```
volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql                         #database data volume
        - ./src/main/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro #database files called when the container is built and started for the first time
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql 8.0\_ Create new db\_ "Schema directory already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454272/mysql-8-0-create-new-db-schema-directory-already-exists)

Comment: I think your `Drop database` does not clear data from volume and it persists inside host machine

Comment: That's correct drop database does not clear data from mysql/data. So even if I restart the server and delete it before nothing happens. even If I remove the container mysql  and then run it I get the same issue `docker-compose rm -v -f mysql && docker-compose up`

Comment: Why not always keep database, just do `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` as I assume you want to fresh start of database? Maybe you do not want to keep database in persistable volume, but somewhere else?